# On replacing JavaConversions with JavaConverters

Tags: scala

When I try to run code based on [**this example**](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-java-system-environment-variables-properties), I get the following warning:

```
warning: object JavaConversions in package collection is deprecated (since 2.12.0): use JavaConverters
```

AFAICT, the lines responsible for the warning are these:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

/* ... */

    for ((k,v) <- environmentVars) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
```

Replacing the `import` line with

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

...is not enough; doing this alone results in the error:

```
error: value withFilter is not a member of java.util.Map[String,String]
    for ((k,v) <- environmentVars) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
```

What else must be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add the `asScala` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

for ((k,v) <- environmentVars.asScala) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
```

Since Scala 2.13, this is now `CollectionConverters`:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

for ((k,v) <- environmentVars.asScala) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd meant to accept this answer right away, but the SO interface got in the way...

Comment: Isn't there an easier way for doing this. for ex. if you have a file with lots of conversions. It was very easy to just import JavaConversions only once.

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy WDYM by "easier way"? you have to explicitly call `asScala`.

Comment: I mean if you have a file with 20 conversions. you will have to call `asScala` 20 times. but before it was just importing `JavaConversions._`

Answer (score 1):

FYI,  scala.collection.JavaConverters has now been replaced with scala.jdk.CollectionConverters